# DRY: How to simplify this duplicated code for date into a funciton?

Tags: javascript

- **Is it possible to stuff it into a function or an array?**
- **How to simplify the code?**

```js
var yesterday = new Date();
    yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);
    yesterday.setHours(03, 0, 0, 0);
    var today = new Date();
    today.setHours(03, 0, 0, 0);
    var tomorrow1 = new Date();
    tomorrow1.setDate(tomorrow1.getDate() + 1);
    tomorrow1.setHours(03, 0, 0, 0);
    var tomorrow2 = new Date();
    tomorrow2.setDate(tomorrow2.getDate() + 2);
    tomorrow2.setHours(03, 0, 0, 0);
    var tomorrow3 = new Date();
    tomorrow3.setDate(tomorrow3.getDate() + 3);
    tomorrow3.setHours(03, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please [check out this guide about asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), so others can help you.

Answer (score 4):

You could move the duplicate code of adding hours and date to function and then use that function as a parameter in [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const getNthDay = (n) => {
  const day = new Date();
  day.setDate(day.getDate() + n);
  day.setHours(03, 0, 0, 0);
  return day;
}

const arrayOfDates = [-1,0,1,2,3].map(getNthDay);

console.log(arrayOfDates)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `map()` method:

```js
const [yesterday, today, tommorow1, tommorow2, tommorow3] = [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3].map(x => {
  const date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + x);
  date.setHours(03, 0, 0, 0);
  return date;
});

console.log(yesterday, today, tommorow1, tommorow2, tommorow3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Map and destructure.

```js
var [yesterday, today, tomorrow1, tomorrow2, tomorrow3] = [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3].map(offset => {
   var d = new Date();
   d.setDate(d.getDate() + offset);
   d.setHours(03, 0, 0, 0);
   return d;
});

console.log(yesterday);
console.log(today);
console.log(tomorrow1);
console.log(tomorrow2);
console.log(tomorrow3);
```